# What make you to define a project in maven or gradle

Tags: maven, project, gradle

I have seen "project" (a system) by using maven or gradle contains so many small projects. The projects are not just parallel, but also contains children projects and children's children projects. This makes the "project" structure rather difficult to understand. My question is What make you to define a project in maven or gradle. My answer would be depends on the reusability. It makes sense to break "project" into different modules and keep them really separate, but if this layer or small module is not going be used by many different other modules, it should be just part of the maven/gradle project. what is your opinion on this? thanks.